# Site creation can't continue because of a configuration issue with the parent site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm having problems to make my site creation work.

I followed the guide at [this blog](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/25/visual-guide-setting-up-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/), everything is setup as what described. If I go to personal site, i.e. `http://my_host.com:80/my/myinc_sp_test`, I can see the new site link. When click it, it pops this error shown in screen shot. What I wanted to do is create the site collect at: `http://my_host.com:80/my/testtest`

However, if I go to this page's site content, create a subsite, it works fine. One subsite url is shown in screen shot with yellow circle. The created subsite is at: `http://my_host.com:80/my/myinc_sp_test/testtest`

myinc is the domain name, it is the prefix for personal site.

anyone knows something about this error? or any clue how I can fix this?

BTW, if I go to `http://my_host.com:80/_layouts/15/scsignup.aspx` , I can see the create team site page, fill in info, click the create button. It shows error with no much other info.

Thanks

[image]

*** BTW, I just know 1 thing: this site collection (my site host) was migrated from another server. Here is how it was done: create web app on this new server, then export content database from the old server, then attach to the new server. after this, everything else works fine. Could it because of this?

**UPDATE: This is odd.** I removed all permissions, add permissions, disable self-service, then enable self-service. Then try to create the site (it is site collection, not subsite under personal site). same error messages. The setting I use is in below screen shot:
[image]

So, I played the settings, and I accidentally changed one setting: I removed the "my/[%userid%]" in the above screen (so it is blank). When I try to create site again, it shows this error:

[image]

I'm using a domain user account. So I think if I use a farm admin account, it should be ok? It turns out YES. It works for farm admin! So, it is because of permission! But what permission? So I removed all user permissions again, and add permissions again (just like i did before), weird thing happened: now, it works for domain user! but only for root domain http://my_host.com/ . I played more and found a more weird thing. See the 2nd screen shot, I choose the "Prompt users to create a site collection under any managed path" (red circle), when I click add new site, it works:

[image]

See the site collection url, `http://my_host.com/my/my_test_site_collection` ? I do not understand what the difference between this and the choice in the 1st screenshot (if I give it a name my_test_site_collection).

**Anyone understand this? to me, I'm ok with it since I can use it (the last screen), but would like to know why it shows error in the first screen.**

Comment: are you shareing the same web App for the MySite host and your other team site? its highly recommended use a separate web app for MySite...

Comment: also make sure...self site creation enabled and users having the permission to create mySite.

Comment: no, the web app is for the MySite host only. Personal site, and subsite under personal site is ok, but can't create MySite. somewhere the permission for site collection creation failed (I think), not sure where/how to check.

Comment: yes, enabled, and have permission. Personal sites and subsites creation works fine. User Site Collection creation failed.

Answer (score 0):

For me lookalike its permission issue. did you grant every user to create team sites.

Perform these additional steps to configure permissions for users to create team sites from their My Sites to use site feeds.

In the Policy group, click Permission Policy.

On Manage Permission Policy Levels dialog box, click Add Permission Policy Level.
Type a name for the permission policy.

Under Permissions, in Site Permissions, select the Grant option for Create Subsites - Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.

Click Save.

In the Policy group, click User Policy.

On Policy for Web Application dialog box, click Add Users.

On Add Users, in Zones select (All Zones), then click Next.

In Choose Users, enter the user names of the users that you want to create team sites from their My Site to use site feeds. If all users can create team sites from their My Site to use site feeds, click the Browse icon. In Select People and Groups, click All Users, then click Everyone. Click Add, and then click OK.

In the Choose Permissions section, select the name of the Permission Policy created previously.

Click Finish, and then click OK.

here is he [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx#enableselfsvc)

Comment: I believe it is permission too. Yes, I did all these steps. Actually, user can create subsite under personal site, i.e. http://my_host.com/my/myinc_myid/my_new_subsite . The error pops when click New Site link on personal site try to create http://my_host.com/my/my_new_site . I think somewhere the user should have permission to create Site Collection under http://my_host.com/my/ . Although it is set already, but it seems not working as designed. I'll disable self-service creation, then enable it. Do not have access to system now, will report back tonight. thanks

Comment: i would check the ULS logs for more in depth error details...meanwhile check the step 11 to 17 from below link an make sure that exist for mysite webapplication.http://sharepoint2013help.blogspot.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-mysite-configuration.html

Comment: thanks. however, every step was followed exactly before. no success. I'll check ULS tonight.

Comment: I just know 1 thing: this site collection (my site host) was migrated from another server. Here is how it was done: create web app on this new server, then export content database from the old server, then attach to the new server. after this, everything else works fine. Could it because of this?

Comment: Another server means another faem? And after creation new web app...did you update the mysite host info if it is changed

Comment: yes, another farm. yes, updated mysite host to pointing to the new farm.

Comment: i would try to create root level site collection in new webapp with mysite template....i am sure you have same wildcard as in old farm....is their any other site collection in the same web app or all the mysites having the same issue....i would wait for uls logs

Comment: On the new farm, I created the new webapp, but no site collection. then attached the content database. everything else is step by step follow books. See my UPDATE in the end of original post. Any idea?